# count numbers in certain intervals

Tags: c, intervals

I want to create a code where it comapres two sets of functions. First, I created 100 random numberand then I want to separate these 100 numbers based on interval [0,1) and sub interval j.
ie. If sub interval j is 10, then 10 equal range of sub intervals will be created between 0 and 1.
0 ~ 0.1, 0.1 ~ 0.2, 0.2 ~ 0.3,...., 0.9 ~ 1.0. I have done these procedures with the code below.

The problem is that I don't know how to count the numbers in these k sub intervals.
For example I don't know how to code so that it shows how many numbers are between 0 ~ 0.1, 0.1 ~ 0.2, 0.2 ~ 0.3,...., 0.9 ~ 1.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define E 2.71828182845904523536


double ran_y(double lambda){    // Equation 2
double u;
u = rand() / (RAND_MAX +1.0);
if(u<0)
    return 0;
else if(u>=0)
    return 1 - pow(E, -lambda * u);
}

double ran_expo(double lambda){ // Equation 3
    double u;
    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double interval, ksub, kint;
    double npt;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   printf("Exponential random variable\n"); // prints out 100 exponential
                                            // random variables
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)                   //
        printf("%f" " ", ran_expo(1));      //

    printf("\n \nNumber of intervals: ");   // value of k-sub intervals
    scanf("%lf", &ksub);                    //

    for(i=0; i<=ksub; i++) {
        interval = 1/ksub;
            kint = i * interval;
                printf("%.3lf ", kint);     // divides into k-sub intervals
    }

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        printf("%f" " ", ran_y(1));
}
```

Comment: Keep a variable count where you are doing the loop for “divides into k-sub intervals” and keep doing ++ for each k-sub

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Is it possible for you to give an example?

Comment: I believe this is the part where you are getting the intervals - `    for(i=0; i<=ksub; i++) {
        interval = 1/ksub;
            kint = i * interval;
                printf("%.3lf ", kint);     // divides into k-sub intervals
    }` just add a counter `int  count = 0     for(i=0; i<=ksub; i++) {
        interval = 1/ksub;
            kint = i * interval;
                printf("%.3lf ", kint);     // divides into k-sub intervals
count++
    }`

Comment: it doesn't seem to count how many numbers are in the intervals. It just displays the intervals and then the random variables after.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define E 2.71828182845904523536


double ran_y(double lambda){    // Equation 2
double u;
u = rand() / (RAND_MAX +1.0);
if(u<0)
    return 0;
else if(u>=0)
return 1 - pow(E, -lambda * u);
}

double ran_expo(double lambda){ // Equation 3
double u;
u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}


int main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    double interval, ksub, kint;
    double npt;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   printf("Exponential random variable\n"); // prints out 100 exponential
                                        // random variables
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)                   //
        printf("%f" " ", ran_expo(1));      //

    printf("\n \nNumber of intervals: ");   // value of k-sub intervals
    scanf("%lf", &ksub);                    //

    for(i=0; i<=ksub; i++) {
    interval = 1/ksub;
        kint = i * interval;
            printf("%.3lf ", kint);     // divides into k-sub intervals
            count++;
    }

for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    printf("%f" " ", ran_y(1));
    printf("%d Intervals in each k-sub", count);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to know the number of intervals. It's the number of random numbers generated between the intervals

Comment: Is this your ask - " how many numbers are between 0 ~ 0.1, 0.1 ~ 0.2, 0.2 ~ 0.3,...., 0.9 ~ 1.0." ?

Comment: Then, what is the `count` you are getting from my code ?

Comment: it counts the number of intervals not the number of random numbers in between the sub intervals.